# Is there a name for the following "special function"?

Tags: functions, polynomials, special-functions

I'm considering a series of polynomial functions defined as follows: let $q\in \mathbb{R}$, $q\neq 0$. For each $n\geq 1$ let
$$
f_n(x):=\prod_{i=1}^nq^ix(1-q^ix).
$$
This series of functions looks like Hermite functions but not the same.

> > My question is: is the above function a well-known special function? If yes, where can I find its properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to the [$q$-Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html),
$$f_n(x):=\prod_{i=1}^nq^ix(1-q^ix)=q^{n(n+1)/2}x^n(qx;q)_{n}.$$